# Linq to Entities where clause on navigation property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this fairly simple SQL query :

```
SELECT i.IdItem
FROM Item i
INNER JOIN Size s ON i.IdItem = s.IdItem
WHERE s.Width > 0 AND s.Width < 100
```

... which I've been trying to translate to LINQ to entities, to no avail.

So far this is what I came up with :

```
context.Items.Where(i => i.Sizes.Where(s => s.Width > 0 && s.Width < 100))
```

I have a `DbSet` in my `DatabaseContext` (context) for both Items and Sizes, my `Item` entity has a `Sizes` navigation property.

This doesn't compile, giving me a `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'` error. I have a feeling I'm missing something really obvious here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
context.Items.Where(i => i.Sizes.Any(s => s.Width > 0 && s.Width < 100))
```

`Where` gives you an `IEnumerable` which cannot be used as a condition